# An identity involving sum of probably binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How could I prove that
$$\sum _{m=v}^n \left(\left(\prod _{k=v}^{m-1} \frac{k^2}{m^2-k^2}\right)\left(\prod _{k=m+1}^n \frac{k^2}{k^2-m^2}\right)(-1)^{m-v}\right)=1$$
or, simplified,
$$\sum _{m=v}^n \prod _{k=v, k \neq m}^{n} \frac{k^2}{k^2-m^2}=1$$

for any positive integers $v$ and $n$, $v \leq n$? I feel this could be somehow related to binomial coefficient identities.

**Why I want it to be true?**

I got this problem while generating formula for eigenvalues of matrix of special type. I noticed that this
$$\sum _{m=u}^n \frac{2(-1)^{m-1}(n!)^2}{m^2(n-m)!(n+m)!} \frac{m (m+u-1)!}{u (2u-1)! (m-u)!}(-4)^{u-1}$$
can be simplified to this
$$\frac{2((u-1)!)^24^{u-1}}{(2u)!}$$

Comment: See FAQ:how to ask

Comment: Gedrox, why do you think this equation is true?

Comment: At least for all $v$ and $n$ less than 50 it is true.

Comment: I think what @TomLeinster means is: what led you to come up with this formula? As your question stands, it gives no indication of the ideas that led you to this formula, nor any hint as to why you want the formula to be true.

Comment: See my edit if it helps..

Comment: You can rewrite the summand as a single product over the set k going from v to n, with k not m. This might be almost as useful as Steven Landsburg's rewrite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the contour integral of 
$$ 
\frac{1}{z} \prod_{k=v}^{n} \frac{k^2}{k^2-z^2} 
$$ 
over a circle of large radius centered at $0$.  Since the integrand is 
small as $|z|\to \infty$ the answer must go to zero as the radius goes to infinity. 
But inside the circle there are poles at $z=0$ and $z= \pm k$ for $k$ from $v$ to $n$. Computing the residues here gives your identity.

Edit in response to OP's comment:  The proof above uses complex analysis and 
the residue theorem; consult any introductory book in that subject.  Alternatively, 
note that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with distinct roots $r_1$, $\ldots$, $r_n$ then 
$$ 
Q(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{P^{\prime}(r_j)} \frac{P(x)}{(x-r_j)} 
$$ 
is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ which also equals $1$ for all the $n$-points $x=r_j$.  Therefore $Q(x)$ is identically $1$.  Your identity follows by taking $P(x) = \prod_{k=v}^{n} (k^2-x^2)$, and evaluating $Q(x)=1$ at $x=0$. 
The general identity $Q(x)=1$ mentioned above is classical, and was discussed on MSE: 
see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104262/sum-of-reciprocals-of-derivative-of-polynomial-at-its-roots

Comment: Thank you! Could you, please, guide me what theorems are used to convert problem from finite sum to contour integral?

Comment: Ok, I've got it! Residue theorem is used on the function you mentioned. And yes -- it's easy to prove that contour integral tends to zero when $R \to \infty$.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the degree $n - v$ polynomial that interpolates the points $(x_i, y_i) = ((v + i)^2, 1)$, with $i = 0, \ldots , n - v$.  This polynomial is $y = 1$, so the Lagrange interpolation formula gives
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{n - v} \prod_{j \neq i} \frac{x - x_j}{x_i - x_j} = 1 .
$$
Setting $x = 0$ gives the identity in the simplified second form.

Comment: That's way too elegant. Surely there is something amiss?

Comment: Bravo.     ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Seems legit. Very nice! Still I would add explanation that polynomial of order $n-v$ which has value $1$ in $n-v+1$ different points in fact is constant function of 1.

Answer (score 1):

(Posted as an answer because it's difficult to make this readable in a comment):

The $m$th term (except for the sign) simplifies to 
$$2\binom{n}{n-m}\binom{m-1}{v-1}\binom{m+v-1}{v-1}\over\binom{n+m}{m}$$